# Adding a List of Razor Views inside a Razor View based on a number added on click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-mvc-5

I need some alternatives.

My scenario is Razor view MVC 5:

```
<div>
    @Html.LabelFor("How many items do you have to explain?", new { @class = "control-label" })
    @Html.DropDownListFor( i => i.ItemCount,
        new SelectListItem[]
        {
            new SelectListItem {Text = "", Value = ""},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "1", Value = "1"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "2", Value = "2"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "3", Value = "3"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "4", Value = "4"},
            new SelectListItem {Text = "5", Value = "5"}
        }, new { @class = "form-control", })
</div>
<div class = "hidden-display" id="itemstoexplin"> @* After item is selected this section would be visible with items like: Name, Width, Height, Cost etc... Pretty much a form of options to fill out.
    @*
        !!! ~ LOGIC:  WHERE CAN I ADD THE NEED VIEWS/PARTIALS BASED ON NUMBER SELECTED ABOVE FROM.
    *@
</div>
```

Where can I add the needed views/partials from based off of the number selected in the Htem.DropDownListFor for a CRUD scenario?

Got any examples of this being done?

Weather it is pushing it through the controller, or JQuery fetch and return, I just need a new set of eyes to feed some examples.

(Not concerned about he show/hide logic, I have no problem doing that portion)

Comment: Seems like you could just use jquery or whatever to hide/unhide views based on that event? So in other words on page load have all views rendered hidden and then just hide/unhide accordingly

Comment: It's not the hide and un-hide I'm concerned about. It's the adding the views.
Thank you though.

I Updated my post to better explain that I'm looking on where I can populate the need section from. Also pointed out that I know how to do the show/hide portion.